# Crop Functionality using FabricJs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How to implement crop tool on the image that is loaded on the canvas using fabric.js ?
I have a image loaded on the canvas .Now i want to implement crop tool where the user is allowed to crop the image and reload it on to the canvas when he is done.

Comment: Do you want to crop an image at the same angle, or also with support for rotation?

Comment: @kangax: Jus like crop tool in paint application . I mean crop an image at the same angle.Simple crop selected area of image

Comment: @kangax:Can we use toDataURL crop feature to crop the image loaded on canvas and reload it back ?

Comment: yes, you can use `img.toDataURL(...)`

Comment: @John did u succeed in getting crop feature like pain?

Comment: yes ...did it using  img.toDataURL(...)

Comment: canvas.toDataURL return different dimension image if there is an zoom in or out is applied to canvas. How does it possible to get image crop on zoomed canvas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Summary

1. set `el.selectable = false`
2. draw a rectangle on it with mouse event
3. get rectangle left/top and width/height
4. then use the following function

Sorry, let me explain. The `ctx.rect` will crop the image from the center point of the object. Also the `scaleX` factor should be taken into account.

```
x = select_el.left - object.left;
y = select_el.top - object.top;

x *= 1 / scale;
y *= 1 / scale;

width = select_el.width * 1 / scale;
heigh = select_el.height * 1 / scale;

object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.rect (x, y, width, height);
}
```

Complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/kNEaX/1/

And check out this http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/hzqrM/ for generating the select box.
And a reference for the Fabric events: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

Comment: How can i draw a select box over a image object ? All i have to do is set image as background and then crop ??? Else How to draw a rectangle over a image object ? Events on other object ?

Comment: updated the fiddle can you please check where iam going wrong ?http://jsfiddle.net/hzqrM/5/ also only the clip is working image is not displayed

Comment: ::Can we use toDataURL crop feature to crop the image loaded on canvas and reload it back ?

Comment: Note that this answer will not work if the original has been rotated first.

Comment: its not working if image is big according to canvas

I have added scaleToWidth and scaleToHeight to canvas image.i am trying to add your code but its not cliping correctly

my code

fabric.util.loadImage(src, function (img) {
    object = new fabric.Image(img);
    
    object.set({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        selectable: false
    });
    object.hasRotatingPoint = true;
    object.scaleX = object.scaleY = 0.25;
    object.scaleToWidth("400");
    object.scaleToHeight("400");
    canvas.add(object);
    canvas.renderAll();
});

Comment: Hi, I have another problem, anyone know here, how can I draw inside that rectangle, if mouse goes out of rectangle, drawing stops, how can I do that?

Answer (score 18):

(This answer is an iteration on the fiddle in [Tom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354910/tom) answer. Thank you, Tom, for getting me down the road.)

You can crop in Fabric.js using either [fabric.Object.clipTo()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clipTo) or [fabric.Object.toDataURL()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toDataURL). The `clipTo()` method retains the original image and displays a crop via a mask. The `toDataURL()` method creates a new image.

My full example uses the `clipTo()` method. I have included a small chunk of code at the end showing the `toDataURL()` method.

**Solution 1**

**Summary**

1. Prepare an invisible rectangle. Have it draw when the user clicks and drags mouse across canvas.
2. When user releases mouse click, clip the underlying image

**Difference's from Tom's answer**

In the fiddle in Tom's answer, there are a couple of minor things I wanted to change. So in my example the differences are

1. The crop box work from left to right and right to left (Tom's works from right to left only)
2. You have more than one chance to draw the crop box (attempting to re-draw the crop box in Tom's causes box to jump)
3. Works with Fabric.js v1.5.0
4. Less code.

**The Code**

```js
 // set to the event when the user pressed the mouse button down
var mouseDown;
// only allow one crop. turn it off after that
var disabled = false;
var rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: 'transparent',
    stroke: '#ccc',
    strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
    visible: false
});
var container = document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect();
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(rectangle);
var image;
fabric.util.loadImage("http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg", function(img) {
    image = new fabric.Image(img);
    image.selectable = false;
    canvas.setWidth(image.getWidth());
    canvas.setHeight(image.getHeight());
    canvas.add(image);
    canvas.centerObject(image);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
// capture the event when the user clicks the mouse button down
canvas.on("mouse:down", function(event) {
    if(!disabled) {
        rectangle.width = 2;
        rectangle.height = 2;
        rectangle.left = event.e.pageX - container.left;
        rectangle.top = event.e.pageY - container.top;
        rectangle.visible = true;
        mouseDown = event.e;
        canvas.bringToFront(rectangle);
    }
});
// draw the rectangle as the mouse is moved after a down click
canvas.on("mouse:move", function(event) {
    if(mouseDown && !disabled) {
        rectangle.width = event.e.pageX - mouseDown.pageX;
        rectangle.height = event.e.pageY - mouseDown.pageY;
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
// when mouse click is released, end cropping mode
canvas.on("mouse:up", function() {
    mouseDown = null;
});
$('#cropB').on('click', function() {
    image.clipTo = function(ctx) {
        // origin is the center of the image
        var x = rectangle.left - image.getWidth() / 2;
        var y = rectangle.top - image.getHeight() / 2;
        ctx.rect(x, y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
    };
    image.selectable = true;
    disabled = true;
    rectangle.visible = false;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas style="border: 1px solid black" id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id=cropB>crop</button>
</body>
```

**Solution 2**

Or, instead of using `clipTo()` like above, we could generate a new image using `toDataURL()`. Something like this

```
$('#cropB').on('click', function() {
    image.selectable = true;
    disabled = true;
    rectangle.visible = false;
    var cropped = new Image();
    cropped.src = canvas.toDataURL({
        left: rectangle.left,
        top: rectangle.top,
        width: rectangle.width,
        height: rectangle.height
    });
    cropped.onload = function() {
        canvas.clear();
        image = new fabric.Image(cropped);
        image.left = rectangle.left;
        image.top = rectangle.top;
        image.setCoords();
        canvas.add(image);
        canvas.renderAll();
    };
});
```

Comment: Why when i comment `onload` still works?, and when a put alert after `toDataURL`, this alert is never fired?

Comment: canvas.toDataURL return different image when there is a zoom applied to canvas. Is there any way to crop image with zoom in and out view

Comment: In your solution 2, quality of the image is very poor due to toDataUrl(). Is there any alternate solution where quality retains (same as original image) and work same as solution 2.

Comment: if it is big image then its not working i have added scaleToWidth and scaleToHeight to fit big image on fabric canvas but its not working

Answer (score 0):

**1) VERSION 1 (moving the crop area)**

https://jsfiddle.net/oriongu/f2yv3r7u/latest/

1. Double click image to start the cropping process
2. Move/Scale cropping area while preventing crop area to to leave image area
3. Deselect crop area to finalize image cropping

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.background = '#FFFFFF';
canvas.renderAll();

var imageUrl = "https://loremflickr.com/400/260";
  
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, function (oImg) {

    // fake initial crop 
    let cropRatio = 50;
  oImg.cropX = 0;
  oImg.cropY = 0;
  oImg.width = oImg.width - cropRatio;
  oImg.height = oImg.height - cropRatio;
  oImg.top = (canvas.height / 2) - oImg.getScaledHeight() / 2;
  oImg.left = (canvas.width / 2) - oImg.getScaledWidth() / 2;
  
  canvas.add(oImg);
  
});

canvas.on({
  'mouse:dblclick': function(obj){ 
    var target = obj.target ? obj.target : null;
    if(target && target.type === 'image'){
      prepareCrop(target);
    }
  }
});

function prepareCrop(e){

  var i = new fabric.Rect({
    id: "crop-rect",
    top: e.top,
    left: e.left,
    angle: e.angle,
    width: e.getScaledWidth(),
    height: e.getScaledHeight(),
    stroke: "rgb(42, 67, 101)",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
    fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    globalCompositeOperation: "overlay",
    lockRotation: true,
  });

  var a = new fabric.Rect({
    id: "overlay-rect",
    top: e.top,
    left: e.left,
    angle: e.angle,
    width: e.getScaledWidth(),
    height: e.getScaledHeight(),
    selectable: !1,
    selection: !1,
    fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
    lockRotation: true,
  });

  var s = e.cropX,
      o = e.cropY,
      c = e.width,
      l = e.height;
  e.set({
    cropX: null,
    cropY: null,
    left: e.left - s * e.scaleX,
    top: e.top - o * e.scaleY,
    width: e._originalElement.naturalWidth,
    height: e._originalElement.naturalHeight,
    dirty: false
  });
  i.set({
    left: e.left + s * e.scaleX,
    top: e.top + o * e.scaleY,
    width: c * e.scaleX,
    height: l * e.scaleY,
    dirty: false
  });
  a.set({
    left: e.left,
    top: e.top,
    width: e.width * e.scaleX,
    height: e.height * e.scaleY,
    dirty: false
  });
  i.oldScaleX = i.scaleX;
  i.oldScaleY = i.scaleY;

  canvas.add(a),
    canvas.add(i),
    canvas.discardActiveObject(),
    canvas.setActiveObject(i),
    canvas.renderAll(),

    //
    i.on("moving", function () {
    (i.top < e.top || i.left < e.left) &&
      ((i.left = i.left < e.left ? e.left : i.left),
       (i.top = i.top < e.top ? e.top : i.top)),
      (i.top + i.getScaledHeight() > e.top + e.getScaledHeight() ||
       i.left + i.getScaledWidth() > e.left + e.getScaledWidth()) &&
      ((i.top =
        i.top + i.getScaledHeight() > e.top + e.getScaledHeight()
        ? e.top + e.getScaledHeight() - i.getScaledHeight()
        : i.top),
       (i.left =
        i.left + i.getScaledWidth() > e.left + e.getScaledWidth()
        ? e.left + e.getScaledWidth() - i.getScaledWidth()
        : i.left));
  });

  i.on("scaling", function () {

  });

  //
  i.on("deselected", function () {
    cropImage(i, e);
    canvas.remove(a);
  });
}

function cropImage(i, e){
    
  // remove plaeholder
  canvas.remove(i);

  //
  var s = (i.left - e.left) / e.scaleX,
    o = (i.top - e.top) / e.scaleY,
    c = (i.width * i.scaleX) / e.scaleX,
    l = (i.height * i.scaleY) / e.scaleY;

  // crop
  e.set({
    cropX: s,
    cropY: o,
    width: c,
    height: l,
    top: e.top + o * e.scaleY,
    left: e.left + s * e.scaleX,
    selectable: true,
    cropped: 1
  });

  canvas.renderAll();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600" style=" border: 2px solid #5d9eab;"></canvas>
<small>Double click on image to start cropping</small><br>
<small>Move or scale crop area as desired</small><br>
<small>Deselect to finish cropping</small><br>
```

**2) VERSION 2 (moving the image canva.com style)**

https://jsfiddle.net/oriongu/0ogmnrwd/latest/

1. Double click image  to start the cropping process
2. Move/Scale image while preventing image to leave crop area
3. Deselect image to finalize cropping

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.background = '#FFFFFF';
canvas.renderAll();

var imageUrl = "https://loremflickr.com/400/260";
  
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, function (oImg) {

    // fake initial crop 
    let cropRatio = 50;
  oImg.cropX = 0;
  oImg.cropY = 0;
  oImg.width = oImg.width - cropRatio;
  oImg.height = oImg.height - cropRatio;
  oImg.top = (canvas.height / 2) - oImg.getScaledHeight() / 2;
  oImg.left = (canvas.width / 2) - oImg.getScaledWidth() / 2;
  
  // add to canvas
  canvas.add(oImg);
});

canvas.on({

    // listen to double click
  'mouse:dblclick': function(obj){ 
    var target = obj.target ? obj.target : null;
    if(target && target.type === 'image'){
      prepareCrop(canvas, target);
    }
  }
});

function prepareCrop(canvas){
  var img = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (img) {

    var s = img.cropX * img.scaleX,
      o = img.cropY * img.scaleY,
      p = img.getScaledWidth(),
      q = img.getScaledHeight();

    console.log('PREPARE CROP', s, o, p, q);

    img.set({
      clipPath: null,
      cropX: null,
      cropY: null,
      left: img.left - s ,
      top: img.top - o ,
      width: img._originalElement.naturalWidth,
      height: img._originalElement.naturalHeight,
      dirty: false,
      opacity: .5,
      lockRotation: true,
      selectable: true,
    });

    // overlay bloc (gray)
    var i = new fabric.Rect({
      id: "crop-rect",
      left: img.left + s,
      top: img.top + o,
      angle: img.angle,
      width: p,
      height: q,
      stroke: "rgb(42, 67, 101)",
      strokeWidth: 1,
      strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
      fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
      lockRotation: true,
      selectable: false
    });

    canvas.add(i);
    canvas.bringToFront(img);
    canvas.renderAll();

    //
    img.on("moving", function () {
      // should constrain image in crop area
      // similar to canva.com crop function
      // we can still increase image scale during this phase
      if(img.left > i.left){ img.left = i.left; } // LEFT
      if(img.top > i.top){ img.top = i.top; } // TOP
      if((img.left+img.getScaledWidth()) < (i.left + i.getScaledWidth())){ img.left = i.left - (img.getScaledWidth() - i.getScaledWidth()); } // RIGHT
      if((img.top+img.getScaledHeight()) < (i.top + i.getScaledHeight())){ img.top = i.top - (img.getScaledHeight() - i.getScaledHeight()); } // RIGHT
    });

    img.on("scaling", function () {
            // to be improved, similar to the moving event
    });

    //
    img.on("deselected", function () {
      cropImage(canvas, i, img);
    });

  }
}

function cropImage(canvas, cropArea, oImg) {

  //
  var cropX = (cropArea.left - oImg.left) / oImg.scaleX,
    cropY = (cropArea.top - oImg.top) / oImg.scaleY,
    width = (cropArea.width * cropArea.scaleX) / oImg.scaleX, // correct
    height = (cropArea.height * cropArea.scaleY) / oImg.scaleY; // correct

  console.log('FINISH CROP', cropX, oImg.scaleX, cropY, oImg.scaleY);

  // crop
  oImg.set({
    cropX: cropX, //
    cropY: cropY, //
    width: width, //
    height: height, //
    top: cropArea.top,
    left: cropArea.left,
    selectable: true,
    lockRotation: false,
    cropped: 1,
    opacity: 1,
  });

  // remove events
  oImg.off('scaling');
  oImg.off('deselected');
  oImg.off('moving');

  // remove crop area
  canvas.remove(cropArea);

}
```

```html
 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600" style=" border: 2px solid #5d9eab;"></canvas>
<small>Double click on image to start cropping</small><br>
<small>Move or scale image as desired</small><br>
<small>Deselect to finish cropping</small><br>
```

Comment: @Yunnosch Great, I managed to get both version to work as intended. I removed all the clutter from the post. Let me know if that's adequate. Thanks.

Comment: @karel As above, it is now a valid answer to OP and I removed all the clutter. Cheers,

Comment: I didn't review this answer before, so there was nothing to remove except for my comment, so I removed the comment.

Answer (score -2):

I developed easy and faster cropping of image using latest fabric js version
https://github.com/kpomservices/Fabric-JS-Image-CROP

Demo: http://kpomservices.com/imagecropdemo/index.html

I used cropx, cropy for maintaining the crop.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: This works pretty well, but when you save the fabric and return to the cropped image, the image disappears when clicked.