# Crop an image using FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, crop, fabricjs

I would like to crop an image using (javascript)FabricJS + HTML5 canvas.

- Background image of canvas is a Fabric image object.
- Crop area
  is a FabricJS Rectangle.

I attached an image too. (you can see what i would like to accomplish)
Is it possible to resize FabricJS canvas somehow to keep only the area selected by rectangle(green dotted rectangle). I think i have all necessary coordinates as you can see on attachment.

Anybody have any ideas/(algorithm,pseudo code) how can i solve it using javascript(FabricJS) ?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732876/crop-functionality-using-fabricjs

Answer (score 0):

The code is already provided in the comment to your question.

But in short what you need to do is listed below:

1. Draw a rectangular on your image (`objectBeingCropped`)
2. Using the function `objectBeingCropped.toDataURL()` to export the cropped area (rectangular area on the image) in blob/url format to another image object's `src`.
3. Now draw the new image which you have the `src` as blob, on canvas using `fabric.Image()`