# Crop multiple images on same canvas using FabricJs

Tags: javascript, canvas, crop, fabricjs

I want to add images to the canvas and select one at a time and apply crop to   please have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/kNEaX/586/

original post: [Crop Functionality using FabricJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732876/crop-functionality-using-fabricjs)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
canvas.backgroundColor = "#333";
canvas.renderAll();

var mouseDown;
var r = document.getElementById('c1').getBoundingClientRect();
var src = "http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg";
var disabled = true;
var scaleX, scaleY
var el


fabric.util.loadImage(src, function(img) {
  object = new fabric.Image(img);
  object.set({
    //      left: 200,
    //      top: 200,
    selectable: true
  });
  object.hasRotatingPoint = true;
  //    object.scaleX = object.scaleY = 0.25;
  canvas.add(object);
  canvas.renderAll();
});




canvas.on("mouse:down", function(event) {
  if (!disabled) {
    el.width = 2;
    el.height = 2;
    el.left = event.e.pageX - r.left;
    el.top = event.e.pageY - r.top;
    el.visible = true;
    mouseDown = event.e;
    canvas.bringToFront(el);
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

canvas.on("mouse:move", function(event) {

  if (mouseDown && !disabled) {
    el.width = event.e.pageX - mouseDown.pageX;
    el.height = event.e.pageY - mouseDown.pageY;
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});


canvas.on("mouse:up", function(event) {
  mouseDown = null;
  if (disabled === false) {
    cropB()
  }
});

$('#cropB-start').on('click', function(event) {

  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (obj) {
    disabled = false;

    el = new fabric.Rect({
      fill: 'transparent',
      stroke: '#ccc',
      strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
      visible: false
    });

    el.visible = false;
    canvas.add(el);
    canvas.renderAll();


    obj.set({
      selectable: false
    })
    canvas.renderAll();
  }else{
  alert('Please select the photo and then click Start Crop, to reset crop click the Reset button')
  }

});

$('#cropB-reset').on('click', function(event) {

  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

  obj.clipTo = null;
  canvas.renderAll();

});

function cropB() {
  var image = canvas.getActiveObject();

  if (image) {
    scaleX = image.get('scaleX'),
      scaleY = image.get('scaleY')

    image.clipTo = function(ctx) {
      // origin is the center of the image
      var x = el.left - image.getWidth() / 2
      var y = el.top - image.getHeight() / 2
      ctx.rect(x, y, el.width * scaleX, el.height * scaleY);
    };
    image.selectable = true;
    disabled = true;
    el.visible = false;
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas style="-moz-user-select: none; cursor: crosshair;" width="400" height="400" id="c1"></canvas>
<button id=cropB-start>Start Crop</button>
<button id=cropB-reset>Reset</button>
```

The problem is that if I add scale to the photo or move the photo, then apply the crop, it does not show the correct crop.

please have a look at the fiddle and see what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

ok all done, I had an issue with the ClipTo coordinates, I needed to take account for the image left and top coordinates and the scale of the image when applying the clipTo function.

have a look at the at the amended function.

```
 function cropB() {

 var image = canvas.getActiveObject();

 if (image) {
   scaleX = image.get('scaleX'),
   scaleY = image.get('scaleY')


     image.clipTo = function(ctx) {

       var x = el.left - image.left - (image.getWidth() / 2),
           y = el.top - image.top - (image.getWidth() / 2),
           width = el.width * 1 / scaleX,
           height = el.height * 1 / scaleY;

           x *= 1 / scaleX;
           y *= 1 / scaleY;

           ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);

      };

         image.selectable = true;
         disabled = true;
         el.visible = false;
         canvas.renderAll();
 }
 };
```