# Calculate the correct area to be cropped fabricjs

Tags: javascript, math, fabricjs, calculation

I want to crop image using fabricJs but I'm stuck on the calculus of the correct area to be cropped.

When I click on the crop button, it doesn't crop the image to the correct area.

The calculation is wrong.

Here's my crop code:

```
function centerXY (w, h) {
    return {
        x: canvas.width / 2 - w / 2,
        y: canvas.height / 2 - h / 2
    }
}
// zoneWidth: width of area where I want to cropped
// zoneHeight: height of area where I want to cropped
 $('#crop').click(function () {
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom()
    const imgTop = canvasImage.top
    const imgLeft = canvasImage.left
    const {x, y} = centerXY(zoneWidth, zoneHeight)
    let top = zoneHeight - imgTop - y
    let left = zoneWidth - imgLeft - x
    zoneWidth /= zoom
    zoneHeight /= zoom

    canvasImage.clipTo = ctx => {
      ctx.rect(left, top, zoneWidth, zoneHeight)
    };
    canvas.renderAll()
  })
```

This calculation is based on this post: [Crop Functionality using FabricJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732876/crop-functionality-using-fabricjs)

**Here's the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58nvte7h/39/).**

**Note:** You can use the input type range to zoom out and see where the image is cropped.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for having the zone crop to be HTML element, instead  of drawing a rectangle in canvas?

Comment: Also, the reference you used is out of date - current version of fabric.js deprecate method `clipTo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
Here's the solution:

```
 $('#crop').click(function () {
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom()
    let top = zoneY // Top position of area 
    let left = zoneX// Left position of area
    zoneWidth /= zoom
    zoneHeight /= zoom

    canvas.clipPath = shapeRect; // fabric.Rect()
    canvas.renderAll()
  })
```

Instead of cropping the image, I cropped the canvas itself.
And Using the position of the area to crop

Here the final demo: https://jsfiddle.net/58nvte7h/43/